# How to get different results from one mysql table?

Tags: mysql

I have a user table in the database where all users of the system are stored.
The table has a user_id and a business_name and a first_name. 
Some users are merchants and get a business name, 
some users are consumers and get a first name.
In a second table I have transactions with a user_id and a merchant_id (which are defining the transaction) and an amount. Both ids reference to user table.

```
Table users:
user_id bus_name first_name role_id
1               Thomas        10
2      comp1                  7
3               Peter         10
4      comp2                  7
(role_id is defining with 10=consumer, 7=merchant)

Table transactions:
trans_id amount user_id merchant_id
1         12     1         2      
2         23     3         2 
3         34     3         4
4         19     1         4
```

Now I want to have a query with a result as one table:
This table should contain the transaction with amount, user_id, first_name, merchant_id and bus_name.

I want to get this result:

```
trans_id amount user_id first_name merchant_id bus_name
1          12     1        Thomas      2         comp1
2          23     3        Peter       2         comp1
3          34     3        Peter       4         comp2
4          19     1        Thomas      4         comp2
```

I have the problem that either I get only the first_name and empty bus_name or I get only the bus_name but empty first_name.
I am using a left join:

```
...
left join `users` 
on(
(`transactions`.`user_id` = `users`.`user_id`)
)
...
```

But for this I would get for user_id=1 the first_name=Thomas and the bus_name='' would be empty because I only reference to one line in table and not also to different user with user_id=2.

But I want to say something like:

```
for trans_id=1
get first_name FROM users WHERE transactions.user_id = users.user_id 
AND
get bus_name FROM users WHERE transactions.merchant_id = users.user_id
```

Thanks for your help, I tried so many things but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to join the user table twice:

```
SELECT t.*, u.first_name, m.bus_name
FROM transactions t
JOIN users as u
  ON t.user_id = u.user_id
JOIN users as m
  ON t.merchant_id = m.merchant_id
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use a duoble join in users table

```
select a.trans_id, a.amount , a.user_id,  b.first_name, a.merchant_id, c. bus_name
from transactions a 
inner join users b on a.user_id = b.user_id and b.role_id = 10
inner join users c on a.merchant_id = c.user_id and c.role_id = 7
```

Answer (score 0):

To join the user table twice worked fine. With "left join `users` as consumer" I create a kind of a virtual users table called "consumer", this one is joined. Of course in select I had to adjust table name as well. Same for second "virtual" table od users, called "merchant".

```
select 
`transactions`.`trans_id` AS `trans_id`,
`transactions`.`merchant_id` AS `merchant_id`,
`merchant`.`bus_name` AS `bus_name`,
`transactions`.`user_id` AS `user_id`,
`consumer`.`first_name` AS `first_name`,
`cards`.`card_id` AS `card_id`,
`cards`.`serial_no` AS `serial_no`
from (
         `transactions` 
             left join `cards`
                on(
                    (`cards`.`card_id` = `transactions`.`card_id`)
                  )
             left join `users` as consumer
                on(
                    (`consumer`.`user_id` = `transactions`.`user_id`)
                  )
             left join `users` as merchant
                on(
                    (`merchant`.`user_id` = `transactions`.`merchant_id`)
                  )


    )
```