# How to return only the rows that above the average in a fully working query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query, that returns a list of rows. Each row has its own `souma` column. The actual return is 26 rows.

What I am trying to achieve but unfortunately can not, is to show only the rows that their `souma` is above `avg(souma)` of **those 26 rows** (not of the entire table).

What changes I must make to do this?

```
SELECT * 
FROM   (SELECT a.*, 
               page, 
               Count(*) AS total 
        FROM   (SELECT *,
                       Sum(percentile_visits_frequency 
                           + percentile_time_spent + percentile_visits 
                           + percentile_last_visit 
                           + Datediff(last_visit, first_visit)) AS souma, 
                       Datediff(last_visit, first_visit)        AS 
                       diafora_imeron 
                FROM   new_table 
                WHERE  company_id = 1 
                       AND Datediff(last_visit, first_visit) > 0 
                GROUP  BY hash 
                ORDER  BY souma DESC, 
                          diafora_imeron DESC) a 
               JOIN behaviour 
                 ON ( behaviour.hash = a.hash ) 
        GROUP  BY page, 
                  hash 
        ORDER  BY total DESC) dd 
GROUP  BY hash 
ORDER  BY souma DESC
```

Comment: Without sample data, current result and expected output we cant dont know what to change.   Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Then you need a subquery

```
 SELECT AVG(souma)
 FROM (SELECT souma
       FROM <yourquery>) as T  --this query is the one returning 26 rows
```

Comment: hi, your answer returns only one row, which is the average. the average in this case is the correct average of the 26 rows. However, I want to output the rows that are above this avg number.

Comment: I saw you ask a very similar question before. As I said if you don't provide sample data, current output and expected output this become a guessing game. Check this question for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45511410/how-to-get-different-results-from-one-mysql-table/45511510#45511510